# Reader.Read() fails to read rows even though it has rows

Tags: c#, oracle, datareader, dbproviderfactories

I have a problem where it appears that the reader indicates that it has rows from the returned SQL but the while loop for the reader never runs.  I put a messagebox in the reader.hasrows as a verification and I put a messagebox on the first line after the while loop as well.  The messagebox for the hasrows is executed but the messagebox for the Read is not executed.  It is very puzzling.  I tried the query against the database and it indeed does return rows.  Here is the code snippet.

```
using (DbConnection connection = CADBase.DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = CADBase.DbConnectionString;
        connection.Open();

        using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            SQL = <statement here>;
            command.CommandText = SQL

            using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
            //NEVER MAKES IT HERE
                    } 
    }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To future readers of this question: note that the problem occurred because the OP was returning too many columns in the query.  See the comments below this answer.

---

I'm not quite sure why this is happening, but you really only need to check for rows once, not twice, and the `Read()` method already does this.

So all you really need is

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Do your thing
}
```

Comment: But if there is more code than `//MAKES IT HERE` around the loop you'll need an additional `bool` variable that you set to `true` when you are in this `while`. To avoid that the property `HasRows` is useful.

Comment: There is no code between makes it here and the while statement.

Comment: @SiliVestige: When I don't know what's wrong, I fix what doesn't look right. You don't need to check twice for rows. Try this; if it still doesn't work, I'll buy you a beer.

Comment: I agree but it is perplexing.  Why would it return that it has rows but never read the rows?  When I take hasrows out I get the same result.  Is there something I can do during the executereader to just grab a value to see if it has one?

Comment: All of the code examples I am seeing in Google all use this form, and don't bother with the HasRows.

Comment: I updated the post with removing hasrows, compiled, and reran the code. No rows are appearing which means there are no rows to be returned. I then took the SQL statement, went to SQLplus targetting the same database and I got a result.  Is there a size problem on reader?  I'm pulling in 64 columns (don't ask me, not my database architecture).

Comment: I guess the only way to find out is to hand the reader some rows that are smaller.

Comment: Whelp.  It appears that there is a limit to the number of columns that can be read.  I dropped the exact query down to one column and it works fine.  I can't find any documentation on the non-wrapped dbreader to see if there is a limit but this wrapped dbreader obviously does.  Thanks for the investigation tips.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess. Maybe you are accessing the reader object in that messagebox shown after reader.HasRows and before reader.Read(). Apparently the Read() method returns true only if the reader has NOT reached the last row (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540626/516481). So if the reader is at the last row it will return false! Maybe the query returns just one row and you change the internal state of the reader object somehow by accessing it (maybe using the debugger) and moving the reader to the last row?

Answer (score 0):

call MoveNext() before first call to read

Answer (score 0):

You should use reader.HasRows property and not the method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're getting an exception on `reader.Read()`.

But since [`HasRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.hasrows.aspx) is a property and not a method. You need to write `if(reader.HasRows)` to make it compile.

```
if(reader.HasRows)
{           
    //MAKES IT HERE   
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //NEVER MAKES IT HERE
    } 
}
```

So i'm wondering what the actual code is.

Comment: That was already made clear in a comment below the question (now deleted).  If you have an actual answer, you should post it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Added a possible(?) reason.

Comment: I think the OP would have mentioned that.  Then again, the code doesn't compile, so.

Comment: The code compiles.  It requires some custom libraries from a vendor.  There is nothing in between the makes it here and while statement.

Comment: _"It requires some custom libraries from a vendor"_ What does that mean? `reader.HasRows()` cannot compile since that's a property not a method.